# Как записать в csv-файл ссылки с которых происходит парсинг

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv, beautiful-soup

Есть код который получает список ссылок `links`, далее из этих ссылок получаем заголовки `h1` и записываем их в `.csv`. Как записать в этот `csv` ссылки страниц с которых мы парсим `h1` (функция: `get_h_content(html, links)`, переменная: `url`)?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    links = []

    ads = soup.find("nav", class_="main-mnu hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs").find("ul").find_all("li")
    for ad in ads:
        urls = ad.find("a").get("href")
        link = "https://gbcrem.by" + urls

        links.append(link)

    return links

def get_h_content(html, links):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    page_url = soup.find_all("body", class_="ishome")

    for ad in page_url:
        try:
            h1 = ad.find_all("h1")
        except:
            h1 = "Нет заголовка"
        try:
            url = links
        except:
            url = "Нет ссылки"

        data = {"h1": h1,"url": url}
        write_csv(data)

def write_csv(data):
    from datetime import date
    today = str(date.today())
    with open(today + "-gbcrem2.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow( (data["h1"],
                                            data["url"]) )      

def main():

    url = "https://gbcrem.by"

    html = get_html(url)
    get_page_data(html)

    get_links = get_page_data(html)
    links = get_page_data(html)
    for url in links:
        html = get_html(url)
        get_h_content(html, links)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было создать переменную `urls` которая в себе хранит ссылки списка `links`. После этого передать переменную `urls` в функцию `get_h_content` и записать в `data`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def vv_pars(first_url, headers):
        session = requests.Session()
        request = session.get(first_url, headers=headers)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("error")

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    links = []

    ads = soup.find("nav", class_="main-mnu hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs").find("ul").find_all("li")
    for ad in ads:
        urls = ad.find("a").get("href")
        link = "https://gbcrem.by" + urls

        links.append(link)

    return links

def get_h_content(html, urls):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    page_url = soup.find_all("body", class_="ishome")

    urll = urls

    for ad in page_url:
        try:
            h1 = ad.find_all("h1")
        except:
            h1 = "Нет заголовка"

        data = {"h1": h1,"urll": urll}
        write_csv(data)

def write_csv(data):
    from datetime import date
    today = str(date.today())
    with open(today + "-gbcrem.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow( (data["h1"],
                                            data["urll"]) )     

def main():

    headers = {"accept": "*/*",
                        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"}
    first_url = "https://gbcrem.by"

    vv_pars(first_url, headers)

    url = "https://gbcrem.by"

    html = get_html(url)
    get_page_data(html)

    links = get_page_data(html)
    for url in links:
        urls = url
        html = get_html(url)
        get_h_content(html, urls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```